# Display static pages with a RAND seed, expiry?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, mod-rewrite, cgi

In Apache, is there any way (using scripts like CGI and PHP, etc.) that will fetch all static content (html, images, and files within a specified size range) and send it to the user as a randomized link, set with a (30 minute for example) expiration? This would preferably not use mod_proxy or it's reverse, as all files will be on the same server. I'm just trying to learn, for a reasonable way to make something like this: http://www.example.com/09-21-2011/USA/CA/article-name.html to appear as http://www.example.com/09-21-2011/USA/CA/randomnumbersandletters (with no .html). I realize the html part can be fixed easily with mod_rewrite.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

There is an example of this working here:
http://memory.loc.gov/frd/cs/httoc.html
Click on any of the links to a section of the article, scroll to the bottom of that page.

Says this:

```
Do NOT bookmark these search results.

Search results are stored in a TEMPORARY file for display purposes. 
The temporary file will be purged from our system in a few hours.
```

Links as this:

```
.../cgi-bin/query/r?randomnumbersandletters
```

Optional function would be to store the temporary sessions in a SQL database and include user IP and time/date accessed.

Comment: This is a terrible idea unless you're also using robots.txt to disallow indexing as it will utterly **destroy** search engine results...

Comment: I planned on doing exactly that but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a system administration problem, it's a programming problem.

---

A quick, ghetto solution algorithm:

1. Establish a session
2. When accessing a page encode some representation of that session along with some representation of the page requested in the URL bar
3. If the session for accessing a document is expired or accessed from an invalid host deny the request

---

An equally ghetto solution for something like `memory.loc.gov` (which *is* actually pulling that data from a separate server and storing it in a temporary location)

1. Establish a session
2. When a file is requested see if we already have it locally in that session's directory.

   - If we have the file, display it (redirect the user or read it in using the scripting language)
   - If we don't have the file retrieve it and stick it in the session's temporary directory, then display as above.
3. When a session's temp directory has not been accessed for `TIME_PERIOD`, delete it.

Comment: Selected as best answer, but note: This provides no information on how to actually govern the task, much like a table of contents of a book. So, a bit vague, but gives me something to work on in the wee hours of dawn.

Comment: @U4iK_HaZe: If the answer doesn't answer your question then there is no requirement to accept it.

Comment: But it was the "best answer available" so I did. A few bonus points to voretaq7 won't even show up.